# Create a custom soft keyboard for Android

Tags: android, keyboard, hex, android-softkeyboard, soft-keyboard

I would like to know how to create a soft keyboard for my Android app specifically one that has numbers 0-9, letters A-F, a decimal point, backspace, and the enter or done button. If you can't tell what it is for, I am trying to program conversions to hexadecimal and using a regular number/letter keyboard can cause the app to crash if there are other letters entered or symbols. Please help, thanks!

Comment: You can still use the regular keyboard and apply a filter to allow only digits, a-f, and decimal point.

Comment: how am I supposed to do that?

Comment: Can you try adding `android:digits="0123456789.abcdef"` flag to your EditText?

Comment: I can also which input method(s) should I use?

Comment: it should work w/o an inputType if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a [tutorial](http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm) to make a keyboard inside your app.
To create a input method with a service: [tutorial](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2009/04/creating-input-method.html)
You will have to set every key you want, then put just numbers and lettters.
To make a key is like this:

```
<Key android:codes="113"    android:keyLabel="q" />
```

Here you can find the [keycodes](https://www.w3.org/2002/09/tests/keys.html).